# How do I get user statistics?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Google Play and iTunes Connect give statistics on who has downloaded my Apps. Google even tells me who still has them installed. But Glass? I don't seem to be able to find any information at all on who has my Glassware installed. OK, fine, I could have installed web bugs in the App but, hey, I didn't! I assumed (ha ha ha) that I'd have the same tools available to me that I had elsewhere! Well... I don't see them. glass-support says that they don't have the information. How does that make sense? If they don't, then who does? Anyone? Anywhere? Thoughts???

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Analytics. I am able to get some demographic info about my Glassware users such as language, country and city. Also, Google Analytics gives the number of new users and returning users. Hope this helps.

Comment: This involves coding something into my app, yes? Just checking! We use GA on our website but that definitely requires coding...